# Conectar dinamicamente num banco Oracle a cada requisição JAX-RS

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, jax-rs

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em JBoss Seam para disponibilizar alguns serviços via JAX-RS no Wildfly 9.

O SGBD usado é o Oracle 10g, e os serviços que serão disponibilizados são de funcionalidades de formulários que a empresa desenvolve no Oracle Forms.

As procedures, functions e triggers do sistema legado são fortemente baseados na variável user do oracle, por causa da auditoria.

Esse comportamento (registrar o usuário que realizou a operação) precisa ser refletido na chamada dos serviços Java que estou desenvolvendo.

Já existe, nas chamadas desse meu serviço, um parâmetro enviado via header que possui informações sobre o usuário, então eu já sei qual usuário vai logar.

A questão é efetivamente logar com esse usuário específico, já que a configuração do datasource do projeto usa um usuário fixo.

O datasource se encontra configurado no arquivo standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/servicesDS" pool-name="servicesDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:<Porta>:<SID></connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name><USER></user-name>
        <password><PASSWORD></password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

...e no persistence.xml...

```
<persistence-unit name="services">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/servicesDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.proc.param_null_passing" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Para produzir os EntityManagers:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class Resources {

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "services")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public FacesContext produceFacesContext() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

}
```

Pesquisei internet a fora e encontrei algo sobre Oracle Proxy, mas só haviam sugestões de uso para EclipseLink. No entanto, o projeto já foi realizado com JPA/Hibernate.

Vocês já passaram por essa situação (configurar dinamicamente essas credenciais da conexão a cada chamada do serviço)? Se sim, foi com JPA/Hibernate?